# object initialzation before initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11

given:

```
class A {
    std::list<int> m_list;
    std::list<int>::iterator m_iterator;
public:
    explicit A() : m_iterator(m_list.begin()) { }
};
```

Am I guaranteed `m_list` will be constructed *before* evaluating ctor initialization list, so that a `begin()` will correctly dereference its beginning/end? Or should I better use an `m_iterator` assignment inside ctor body?

Comment: Note that here `m_iterator` will always be equal to `m_list.end()`, as it is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Members are constructed in declaration order.

So **yes** `m_list` will be constructed before `m_list.begin()` will be called.